# How to insert the Echarts in the Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to add the echarts in the template having folder structure

```
ecomponents---->BarCharts.js
Vue-Echarts.vue
```

The code have written in the BarCharts.js file is :-

```
import { IEcharts } from 'vue-echarts-v3/src/full.js';

const data = {
labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
datasets: [
   {
      label: 'GitHub Commits',
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',
      borderColor: '#f87979',
      fill: false,
      data: [40, 20, 60, 80, 65, 89, 40]
   },
   {
     label: 'New Commits',
     backgroundColor: 'green',
     borderColor: 'green',
     fill: false,
     data: [20, 30, 45, 60, 25, 66, 69]
  }
]
}

const options = {

}

export default {
extends: IEcharts,
mounted() {
   // Overwriting base render method with actual data.
   this.renderChart(data, options)
}
}
```

And code in VueEchart.vue is:-

```
  <template>
    <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 lg6 md12 sm12>
          <app-card-block heading="Bar Chart">
           <IEcharts :height="250"></IEcharts>
          </app-card-block>
        </v-flex>
     </v-layout>
    </v-container>   
  </template>

 <script>
 import BarChart from "./ecomponents/BarChart";


export default {
 components: {
  BarChart
 }
}
```

This will shows me this error:-

> [WDS] Errors while compiling. Reload prevented.
>       errors @ client:155
>       onmessage @ socket.js:41
>       EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
>       (anonymous) @ sockjs.js:883
>       SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:881
>       EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
>       WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2957
>       client:161 ./node_modules/vue-echarts-v3/src/full.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'echarts' in 'D:\vue\speedvue\node_modules\vue-echarts-v3\src'
>       errors @ client:161
>       onmessage @ socket.js:41
>       EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
>       (anonymous) @ sockjs.js:883
>       SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:881
>       EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
>       WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2957
>       vue-router.esm.js:17 [vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default:Error: Cannot find module 'echarts'
>       warn @ vue-router.esm.js:17
>       (anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1764
>       (anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1834
>       vue-router.esm.js:17 [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
>       warn @ vue-router.esm.js:17
>       abort @ vue-router.esm.js:1905
>       (anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1948
>       (anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1769
>       (anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1834
>       vue-router.esm.js:1906 Error: Cannot find module 'echarts'
>       at webpackMissingModule (full.js:2)
>       at eval (full.js:2)
>       at Module../node_modules/vue-echarts-v3/src/full.js(21.fb0a995c.chunk.js:178)
>       at **webpack_require** (main.78994579.js:64)
>       at eval (BarChart.js:2)
>       at Module../src/views/Charts/VueChartjs/ecomponents/BarChart.js(23.2464eff6.chunk.js:47)

How will I solve this error can any one tell me how to implement this echart.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant errors here are `Error: Can't resolve 'echarts' in 'D:\vue\speedvue\node_modules\vue-echarts-v3\src'` and `Error: Cannot find module 'echarts' at webpackMissingModule`.

What does this mean? Your package `vue-echarts-v3` requires the `echarts` package, but apparently has not properly listed it as a dependency. The package was thus not installed automatically when you installed `vue-echarts-v3`. You can fix the issue by running `npm install echarts`.